# How to select multiple cells on Mac when using Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Tags: mac, remote-desktop

I need to select multiple cells, on Mac the usual shortcut is CMD + cursor. But when using Microsoft Remote Desktob CMD button is interpreted as Windows key, that is, when I pusch cmd, the startup menu pops up. How can I select multiple cells that are not adjacent to each other when on Microsoft Remote Desktop?

Comment: Are you sitting at a Mac and connecting to a remote Windows computer, or sitting at a Windows computer and connecting to a remote Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for operations of this type, not <kbd>Command</kbd>

- Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click to make non-contiguous selections.
- Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-Click to make contiguous selections.